# Keeping session/cookie separate in two folders

Tags: php, session, cookies

I have two folders on my domain. `/builder` and /`viewer`. Each one functions independently from another, so when I set a cookie or session variable on one, I don't want it to affect the other.

I tried to modify `session_set_cookie_params` to

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, "/viewer");
```

Then also changed `setcookie` to

```
setcookie(
  "$name",
  "$value",
  time() + ($days * 24 * 60 * 60),
  "/viewer"
);
```

Now my viewer script doesn't seem to be able to read the cookies set. I figured I'm doing something wrong, I didn't think I needed to specify the domain parameter, but I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

**memcache/memcached session handler**

You can set a new prefix witch acts like a namespace:

```
ini_set('memcached.sess_prefix', 'memc.sess.builder.key.');
ini_set('memcached.sess_prefix', 'memc.sess.viewer.key.');
```

**file session handler**

`mkdir` 2 directories under `/tmp`: `/tmp/sess_builder/` and `/tmp/sess_viewer` then

```
session_save_path('/tmp/sess_builder/');
session_save_path('/tmp/sess_viewer/');
```